# Overfull \hbox with minipage and \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

Tags: minipage, parskip, parfillskip

The following MWE produces the warning `Overfull \hbox (30.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--12`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
    b
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
    a
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Removing `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` and placing `\noindent` before the first minipage resolves the issue for this MWE, but that does not help as the parskip package seems to work better for two-column documents than allowing regular indentation. (The stated issue does not change when `twocolumn` is added as an option for `article`, either.) Removing the `%` and changing the widths to something like `0.43\columnwidth` to prevent the resultant automatic line breaking due to the additional space (using a non-breaking space still means decreasing the minipage widths to avoid another overfull warning) seems to resolve it as well, but given the behavior with respect to `parskip`/`\noindent` I feel like there should be a different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parfill` option sets \parfillskip to 30pt. This means that TeX tries to leave at the end of a paragraph a space of 30pt. This doesn't work with your minipages. You can locally reset \parfillskip:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}
\begingroup \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
    b
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
    a
  \end{minipage}%
\par\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, I just found that removing `parfill` also resolves the issue (but I don't like how my document looks without `parfill` as the minimum distance between paragraphs becomes too small). It doesn't seem that the percent signs after `\setlength` or the second `minipage` end are necessary, though, at least not for the current context of the minipages in my document (there doesn't seem to be any visual difference in spacing). Anyway, thanks!