# Inline todonotes and parfillskip lead to overfull \hbox

Tags: todonotes, parskip, parfillskip

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  % parskip=half,  % 1em; overfull \hbox \hbox (10.45003pt)
  % parskip=half*, % .25\linewidth; Overfull \hbox (104.06389pt too wide)
  parskip=half+,   % 0.33333\linewidth; Overfull \hbox (138.90363pt too wide)
  % parskip=half-, % No overfull \hbox
  % parskip=false, % No overfull \hbox (default)
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{todonotes}
% \usepackage{luatodonotes}
% \usepackage{lua-visual-debug} % show boxes

\begin{document}
\the\parfillskip
\todo[inline]{hello}
\end{document}
```

If you compile this, you will get an overfull `\hbox` which apparently is an incorrect overfull `\hbox` warning which is only be triggered because the inline todonotes take the full linewidth and then `\parfillskip` is added.  The package `luatodonotes` has the same issue.

How can one fix this? (probably the package itself should be fixed)

Package versions affected (last update 27.01.2019):

- `todonotes`:

  - `2015/07/09 v1.0.4`
  - `2019/01/24 v1.1.2`
- `luatodonotes`

  - `2015/12/03 v0.3`
  - `2017/09/30 v0.4`

Related questions:

- [Overfull \hbox with minipage and \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308891/overfull-hbox-with-minipage-and-usepackageparfillparskip/308892#308892)
- [Make \section unaffected by \parfillskip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151680/make-section-unaffected-by-parfillskip)

Comment: Send a bug report to the authors of `todonotes` and `luatodonotes`.

Comment: Nope. I contacted the author in March 2017 via Email but never got an answer. Sorry.